# TFS 2015: Get all first level children's of a parent omitting other level children's

Tags: tfs

How can I define a query in TFS 2015 (Team Explorer 2015) to get only the first level children's of a parent and not the children's of children's?

- Parent 1

  - Child 1

    - Child of Child 1
  - Child 2

    - Child of Child 2

Result:

- Parent 1

  - Child 1
  - Child 2

Answer (score 0):

In the `Type of query` choose "Work items and direct links" and in the `Type of links` choose "Return selected link types - Child".

[image]